# Lifting of principal G-bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, fiber-bundles, deformation-theory

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field.
We assume all schemes we consider are $k$-schemes.

Let $P \rightarrow X$ be a principal $G$-bundle, where $G$ is an algebraic group.
We assume $X$ is affine $(X := \text{Spec}(A))$.

Let $X  \rightarrow X' := \text{Spec}(A')$ be a thickening.
Note that thickening means $X \rightarrow X'$ is a closed immersion and its ideal sheaf is nilpotent.

Then, do we have a lifting of the principal bundle $P$ ?
I.e., We have the following cartesian diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
P @>>> P'\\
@VVV @VVV\\ X
@>>> X'
\end{CD}

, where $P' \rightarrow X'$ is also a principal $G$-bundle ?

Edit :
I originally came across this problem in the following question.

Let $Y$ be a $k$-scheme with a $G$-action and $P \rightarrow Y$ be a $G$-equivariant morphism ($P$ is defined as above).

Then, classify the liftings of $P \rightarrow Y$ to $P' \rightarrow Y$ s.t. they are also $G$-equivariant if a lifting $P' \rightarrow X'$ of a principal $G$-bundle $P \rightarrow X$ with respect $X \rightarrow X'$ exists.

Comment: Does principal bundle mean principal bundle for the etale topology? If so, the answer should be yes since such principal bundles are classified by $H^1_\mathrm{et}(X,G)$ but the natural map $H^1_\mathrm{et}(X',G)\to H^1_\mathrm{et}(X,G)$ is a bijection since the morphism $X\to X'$ induces an equivalence on etale sites since it's a universal homeomorphism.

Comment: Yes! We consider in the etale topology.

Comment: And, how do we prove the existence of the map $H^1_\text{et}(X',G) \rightarrow H^1_\text{et}(X,G)$ and it is a bijection ?

Comment: Hey, I think there is an issue with my answer, and I'd like to return to it in a few days when I have more time. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: The issue that I made the mistake on is embarassingly basic: the map $p:X\to X'$ induces an isomorphism $H^1_\mathrm{et}(X',G)\to H^1_\mathrm{et}(X,p^\ast(G))$, but $p^\ast(G)\ne G$.  Will think more and try to respond later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I wrote down before is wrong--in particular, I seemed to imply that one didn't need affineness hypotheses, but this is definitely not true (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/873214/16497)).

I think I am reinventing the wheel here (showing that I had a non-ideal grasp on the involved deformation theory before), and most of this is probably contained in **leibnewtz** reference, but since it makes sense to me now I thought I'd try to explain it.

---

Throughout the following, we make the following assumption:

> **Asssumption:** Let $S$ be some affine base scheme, and $G$ an affine smooth group scheme over $S$.

**NB:** You can remove most of these assumptions, but for clarity let's ignore them for now.

For simplicity, for a morphism $X\to S$, let we will abusively write $G$ for $G_X$, since it will always be clear from context what is meant.

We then have the following cohomological classification of principal homogenous spaces (this is where the assumptions are tacitly used).

> **Theorem 1(cf. [Mil, Theorem 4.3]+[Gro, Theorem 11.7])**: Let $X\to S$ be some morphism. Then, there are natural bijections
>
> $$\mathbf{PHS}_G(X)\xrightarrow{\approx}H^1_\mathrm{fppf}(X,G)\xrightarrow{\approx}H^1_\mathrm{et}(X,G).$$

Here $\mathbf{PHS}(X)$ is the set of isomorphism classes of principal homogenous $G$-spaces $P\to X$, and the latter two hopefully are clear (they're non-abelian cohomology with values in the fppf/etale site: see [Poo, Chapter 6]).

Now, as is well-known (see [Tag 04DY](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04DY)), if $p:X\to X'$ is a thickening (over $S$) then it induces an equivalence of etale sites $p_\ast: \mathrm{Sh}(X_\mathrm{et})\to \mathrm{Sh}(X'_\mathrm{et})$. In particular, one sees that one has an induced isomorphism

$$H^1(X_\mathrm{et},G)\xrightarrow{\approx}H^1_\mathrm{et}(X',p_\ast(G)).$$

Unfortunately, and this is where my original mistake was made, one does not, in general, have an isomorphism $p_\ast(G)\cong G$. Let us note though that there is a natural map $G\to p_\ast(G)$ which on some morphism $T'\to X'$ is the natural map $G(T')\to G(T)$ where I am writing $T:=T'\times_{X'}X$, but this is not an isomorphism.

To elucidate this, let us note that since etale morphisms $T'\to X'$ where $T'$ is affine is a basis for $X'_\mathrm{et}$ (and similarly for $X_\mathrm{et}$) we may assume without loss of generality that $T'=\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ and then thus that $T=\mathrm{Spec}(A/I)$ where $\widetilde{I}=(T'\to X')^\ast(\mathcal{I})$, and where $\mathcal{I}$ is the thickening ideal of $X\to X'$. Note then that our map $G\to p_\ast(G)$ is just the map which on $T'=\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ is given by $G(A)\to G(A/I)$ given by reducing modulo $A/I$. So, it's clear somehow that we have a short exact sequence

$$1\to \mathcal{K}\to G\to p_\ast(G)\to 1\qquad\qquad(1)$$

where $\mathcal{K}(A)=G(1+I)$, which is a subgroup of $G(A)$.

Now, here's the key point, if $\mathcal{I}$ is a square-zero ideal (which we can always reduce to by filterting our thickening by squarei-zero thickenings) then one actually has inverse isomorphisms

$$G(1+I)\xrightarrow{\log}\mathrm{Lie}(G)(I),\qquad \mathrm{Lie}(G)(I)\xrightarrow{\exp}G(1+I)$$

(which, if you want to work explicitly, is the obvious thing once you choose an embedding $G\hookrightarrow \mathrm{GL}_n$). In particular, we see that $\mathcal{K}$ is quasi-coherent.

Now, from (1) we have an exact sequence of non-abelian cohomology sets (see

$$1\to \mathcal{K}(X)\to G(X')\to p_\ast(G)(X')(=G(X))\to H^1_\mathrm{et}(X',\mathcal{K})\to H^1_\mathrm{et}(X',G)\to H^1_\mathrm{et}(X',p_\ast(G))(=H^1_\mathrm{et}(X,G))\to H^2_\mathrm{et}(X',\mathcal{K}).$$

(NB: we only get this last $H^2$ term since $\mathcal{K}$ is abelian). Now, combining this and Theorem 1 we see that we get an exact sequence of pointed sets

$$\mathbf{PHS}_G(X')\to\mathbf{PHS}_G(X)\to H^2_\mathrm{et}(X',\mathcal{K})(=H^2_\mathrm{Zar}(X',\mathcal{K})).$$

(see [Tag 03P2](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/03P2) for this last equality). Aha, we see the point. Given any principal homogenous $G$-space $P\to X$ there is an associated *deformation class* $[P]\in H^2_\mathrm{et}(X',\mathcal{K})$ which has the property that $P\to X$ admits a lift to a principal homogenous space $P'\to X'$ if and only if this class $[P]$ vanishes. *But*, the point is that if $X$, and thus $X'$, is affine then the quasi-coherentness of $\mathcal{K}$ forces $H^2_\mathrm{Zar}(X',\mathcal{K})$ to vanish.

This is the classical reason that one needs **affineness hypotheses** when doing the infinitesimal lifting criterion as in **leibnewtz** answer.

I hope this clarifies things!

**References:**

[Gro] Grothendieck, A., 1966. Le groupe de Bauer III: exemples et compléments. IHES.

[Mil] Milne, J.S., 2016. Étale Cohomology (PMS-33), Volume 33. Princeton university press.

[Poo]Poonen, B., 2017. Rational points on varieties (Vol. 186). American Mathematical Soc..

Comment: Thank you very much ! In particular, if $A \rightarrow A'$ is a small extension (i.e $A', A$ are Artin local rings and Ker$(A' \rightarrow A)\mathcal{m}_{A'} = 0 $), do you know anything in more detail ?

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation ! We can find the obstruction of a lifting of $P$ in the cohomology $H^2(X', \mathcal{K})$ isn't it ? And, as you said, affineness hypothesis is important.

Comment: @Walterfield That's correct! Glad it helped.

Comment: +1 for actually giving a proof, as well as explaining why affineness is needed

Answer (score 3):

This follows from the infinitesimal lifting criterion for smoothness: An algebraic stack $\mathcal{X}$ locally of finite type is smooth if and only if for every nilpotent thickening $S \to S'$ of affine schemes, any map $S \to \mathcal{X}$ extends to $S'$. If $G$ is an algebraic group, its classifying space $BG := [pt/G]$ is an algebraic stack locally of finite type for the etale topology. This is so simply because $BG$ has a smooth cover by a point.

I'm not sure what the best reference is for the infinitesimal lifting criterion, but you can see one direction of the proof on page $36$ [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1104.4828.pdf).

Comment: Hey sorry for adding another answer, I was in the process of writing it when you added yours. Thanks! +1

Comment: Thank you very much ! This is very clear answer. My question is equivarent to smoothness of the classifying space BG, isn't it ?

Comment: @Walterfield It is indeed equivalent as you say. The slogan is "locally of finite type + formally smooth = smooth", where "formally smooth" means satisfying the infinitesimal lifting criterion.

Comment: @AlexYoucis No need to apologize. I think multiple perspectives are always valuable